# Not listing data by using of MongoMapper scope throwing error <Plucky::Query status: "Active">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongomapper

Actually I have created two model by using mongomapper concept and i mentioned scope for fetching active authors but its throwing error like

Model 1:

```
class Author
  include MongoMapper::Document         

  key :name, String
  key :status, String

  validates_presence_of :name
  many :books

  scope :active, where(:status => 'Active')

end
```

model 2 :

```
class Book
  include MongoMapper::Document         

  key :title
  key :author_id, ObjectId
  key :status, :default => 'Active'

  validates_presence_of :title

  belongs_to :author

  scope :active, where(:status => 'Active')

end
```

View :

```
Author.active.collect{|a| [a.name,a.id]}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your models as supplied, the view query works for me with a simple example.

test/unit/author_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class AuthorTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Author.delete_all
    Book.delete_all
  end

  test "scope active" do
    puts "\nMongoMapper::Version:#{MongoMapper::Version}"
    Author.create(name: 'J. K. Rowling', status: 'Active')
    a = Author.active.collect{|a| [a.name,a.id]}
    assert_equal("J. K. Rowling", a.first.first)
    p a
  end
end
```

$ rake test

Run options:

```
# Running tests:

[1/1] AuthorTest#test_scope_active
MongoMapper::Version:0.12.0
[DEPRECATED] The 'safe' write concern option has been deprecated in favor of 'w'.
[["J. K. Rowling", BSON::ObjectId('535966d77f11ba2632000001')]]
Finished tests in 0.058895s, 16.9794 tests/s, 16.9794 assertions/s.
1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```